# What is equivalent of fopen_s() in java?

Tags: java, c++

I want to convert this code in java

```
fopen_s(&stream, "path", "w+");
```

`w+` opens empty file with both reading and writing. If the given file exists, it's contents are destroyed.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Java programmer, but I had a short hunt around the web and it seems Java has a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and you open it with the mode `"rw"`.

Comment: No need to check; just setLength(0);

Comment: Ahh cheers for that.  I had to run off while I was writing, and sorta forgot to check I'd answered the whole question =/

Answer (score 3):

It seems 1.7 java is required for the nio, so my take is

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(name, "rw");
f.setLength(0);
```

Comment: Thanks man, sorry cannot make your answer as best but your answer is correct too and thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The true equivalent is to use [`Files.newByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29).

```
final SeekableByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get("path"),
    StandardOpenOptions.READ, StandardOpenOptions.WRITE,
    StandardOpenOptions.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

> The `READ` and `WRITE` options determine if the file should be opened for reading and/or writing.
>
> ...
>
> `TRUNCATE_EXISTING` - If this option is present then the existing file is truncated to a size of 0 bytes. This option is ignored when the file is opened only for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want either [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) or [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), depending on what kind of data you want to write. Either of them can be instantiated with a filename.

```
FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/path/to/file2");
```

And both will clobber the file if it already exists. (Though constructors exists for appending instead of over-writing)

Comment: Not to mention this will not truncate, merely clobber.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to achieve what you want:

```
import java.io.*;
// Create a new file output connected to "myfile.txt"
out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");
// Create a new file input connected to "myfile.txt"
in = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
```

You might want to take a look at the java.io package [at the official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html), especially the [RandomAccessFile Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and [also this quick guide](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java103/java103.html).